# What Event Is Sent Before Url Request?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Is there a way to get the url string before the request is sent to the website? I found a post about it here:

https://forums.mozilla.org/addons/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=11259&p=26111

but I could not find anything about how to "hook into the Browser:OpenLocation command" in the addon SDK.

Basically what I am doing is this:

1. Check the url that is about to be requested to see if it matches my RegExp.
2. If it matches, change the userAgent that is sent to the website. (By setting general.userAgent.override)

Thus I cannot check the url after the page starts loading since the request will have already have been sent, and I would rather not reload the page as it would delay browsing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, check out the docs here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/School_tutorial/Intercepting_Page_Loads#HTTP_Observers

This code will work for the add-on sdk, it checks that the url matches `mysite` and then sets a `MyBrowser/1.0` User-Agent for just that site.  This does the change only when detected, not using the pref userAgent.orverride.

```
var chrome = require("chrome");

chrome.Cc["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"].getService( chrome.Ci.nsIObserverService ).addObserver({
    observe : function(subject, topic, data) {
            var channel = subject.QueryInterface( chrome.Ci.nsIHttpChannel );
            if ( /mysite/.test( channel.originalURI.host ) ) {
                channel.setRequestHeader("User-Agent", "MyBrowser/1.0", false);
            }
    }
},"http-on-modify-request",false);
```